# How to know if a macro has been defined during compilation?

Tags: c, macros

Let us say in some part of the code that a macro has been defined. During compilation, I want to learn if it has been defined and is being used. How might I do this?

Comment: "has been defined" and "being used" are two separate concepts. Checking for definition of a macro identifier is simple and can be done at compile time, but checking for usage (or proper usage) in a codebase is not possible at compile time.

Comment: what do you mean by "is being used"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with `#ifndef` directive and throw an error with `#error` directive :

```
#ifndef A_MUST_HAVE_MACRO
#error "A must have macro not defined"
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

```
#ifdef MACRO
// ... (code here will only be compiled if macro is defined)
#endif
```

or

```
#if defined(MACRO)
// ...
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the gcc compiler, then you can find out if it is being used (and, indirectly, if it was defined) by using the -E option.  gcc's man pages says the following:

> ```
>    -E  Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper.  
>    The output is in the form of preprocessed source code, which is sent 
>    to the standard output.  Input files which don't require preprocessing 
>    are ignored.
> ```

I presume other compilers will have similar options.  Try to find an option that stops after the preprocessing stage (which is where macros are replaced).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to halt compilation if something is or isn't defined, use the C Preprocessor's [`#error`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Diagnostics.html) directive.
Example from that page:

```
 #ifdef __vax__
 #error "Won't work on VAXen.  See comments at get_last_object."
 #endif
```

Will cause a compile error with that message.